# Drilldown United states city/county map from states using highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, maps, r-highcharter

I have two data sets df_state and df_city.

df_state has a summed up of a numeric value(net_value_x).

df_city has a break down of the numeric value(value_x) at city level

This is just a sample for the sate Texas:

df_state:

```
state_abb, net_value_x
.
.
TX        18.94
.
.
```

df_city:

```
state_abb, city, value_x
.
.
TX        Dallas   14
TX        Houston  2
TX        Austin   2.94
.
.
```

This is the code i used to plot at state level using `hcmap` function from `highcharter`.

```
hcmap("countries/us/us-all", data = df_state, value = "net_value_x",
  joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"), name = "net_value_x",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),
  borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
  tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2))
```

This is the map that i get. Hovering sample data for Texas.

[image]

What I need is to drill down this further into city level. Also i may get county level data in the future.

I am visualizing something like this in the link:
[highchart drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-drilldown/)

Comment: I don't know much about R, but I prepared example of how it can be done in pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lkn7fbpf/ Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Have you found an answer to that??

Answer (score 0):

While the drilldown feature of highcharter is useful, when you have data in every state, it would require loading the map for each underlying state at render. An approach I have taken is to essentially switch between plotting the state map and a county map as follows.

```
## Library
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(stringr)

## Load maps at start for speed
maps <- sapply(
  X = c("us-all", "us-tx-all"),
  simplify = FALSE,
  FUN = function(x) { highcharter::download_map_data(paste0("countries/us/", x)) }
)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  highcharter::highchartOutput(outputId = "map"),
  shiny::uiOutput(outputId = "ui")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## USA map with just TX as example
  state_map <- shiny::reactive({
    highcharter::highchart() %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series_map(
        map = maps[["us-all"]],
        df = data.frame(state_abbr = c("TX"), y = c(10)),
        joinBy = c("postal-code", "state_abbr"),
        value = "y"
      ) %>%
      highcharter::hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(
          allowPointSelect = TRUE,
          events = list(
            click = htmlwidgets::JS(
              "function(event) {
                 Shiny.setInputValue(
                   'geo_click', 
                   event.point.state_abbr, 
                   {priority: 'event'}
                 );
              }"
            )
          )
        )
      )
  })

  ## County map
  county_map <- shiny::reactive({
    highcharter::highchart() %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series_map(
        map = maps[[paste0("us-", stringr::str_to_lower(input$geo_click), "-all")]],
        df = data.frame(city = c("Gray", "Leon", "Lamb", "Duval"), y = c(1, 4, 2, 3)),
        joinBy = c("name", "city"),
        value = "y"
      )
  })

  ## Set to state map at outset
  output$map <- highcharter::renderHighchart({ state_map() })

  ## If state clicked, add button to go back to state map
  output$ui <- shiny::renderUI({
    if (!is.null(input$geo_click)) {
      shiny::actionButton(
        inputId = "geo_button",
        label = "Return to USA Map"
      )
    }
  })

  ## If button clicked, reset input, hide button, and go back to state map
  shiny::observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$geo_button,
    handlerExpr = {
      output$map <- highcharter::renderHighchart({ state_map() })
      shinyjs::hide(id = "geo_button")
    }
  )

  ## If state clicked, go to county map and show button
  shiny::observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$geo_click,
    handlerExpr = {
      output$map <- highcharter::renderHighchart({ county_map() })
      shinyjs::show(id = "geo_button")
    }
  )
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```